# Klenke's Proof of De Finetti's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, analysis, permutations

There's a technical problem I ran into when working through Klenke's proof of De Finetti's theorem (Theorem 12.24 on Klenke's Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course, pages 239-240).

The notation is this: let $S(n)$ denote the set of finite permutations that move only the first $n$ items; for $X = (X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\rho\in S(n)$, denote $X^\rho = (X_{\rho(1)},X_{\rho(2)},\dots)$. Let $\varphi_k$ be defined as follows:
$$\varphi_k(x_1,\dots,x_k) = \prod_{i=1}^k f_i(x_i)$$
where $f_i$ are bounded and measurable. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and function $\varphi$, denote
$$A_n(\varphi)= \frac1{n!}\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi(X^\rho)$$
to be the $n$-th symmetric average of the function $\varphi$. If $\varphi$ is only defined for the first few coordinates, extend it naturally to the entire sequence (i.e. $\varphi(X) = \varphi(X_1,\dots,X_k)$, for example).

I'm having trouble proving the following result that Klenke states:
$$A_n(\varphi_k) + R_{n,k} = A_n(\varphi_{k-1})A_n(f_k)$$
where we have
$$|R_{n,k}|\leq 2 \|\varphi_{k-1}\| \|f_k\| \frac1{n!}\frac1n \sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in\sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}}.$$

Here is my attempt so far. We first have
$$A_n(f_k) = \frac1{n!}\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} f_k(X^\rho) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f_k(X_i)$$
since $f_k$ only takes one coordinate as an argument. Further, notice that (please let me know if this is correct)
$$\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho)=\left(\sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n f_k(X_i)\right) - \sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in \sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}} \varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho) f_k(X_i)$$
where the subtracted term takes care of the multiplications that lead $i$ to be "double-counted". We therefore have the following
$$A_n(\varphi_{k-1})A_n(f_k) - A_n(\varphi_k) = \frac1{n!}\frac1n \left(\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho) + \sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in \sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}} \varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho) f_k(X_i)\right) - \frac1{n!} \sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho).$$
The above can be simplified to
$$\frac1{n!}\frac1n \left(\sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in\sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}}\varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho) f_k(X_i)\right) + \frac1{n!} \left(\frac{1-n}{n}\right) \sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho).$$
But the second term does not vanish as $n$ approaches infinity whereas $R_{n,k}$ does. The first term does vanish, but the second term is still there.

I've been working on this for a long time, but still haven't been able to resolve this. Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue: the equation
$$\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho)=\left(\sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n f_k(X_i)\right) - \sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in \sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}} \varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho) f_k(X_i)$$
is incorrect and should be
$$\sum_{\rho\in S(n)} \varphi_k(X^\rho)=\frac{n-k!}{n-k+1!}\left(\left(\sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n f_k(X_i)\right) - \sum_{\rho\in S(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{i\in \sigma\{1,\dots,k-1\}} \varphi_{k-1}(X^\rho) f_k(X_i)\right)$$
instead. The reason is that the product of sum would lead things to be counted many more times, even after the subtraction. Plugging this into the steps in the question would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$A_n(\varphi_k) = \frac{1}{(n)_k}\sum_{i_1, \dots, i_k}\varphi(x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_k}) =: \frac{1}{(n)_k}S_k,$$
where the sum is over all distinct $i_1, \dots, i_k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and
$$(n)_k = n(n - 1) \dots (n - k + 1).$$

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
    A_n (\varphi_{k - 1}) A_n (f_k) & = & \frac{1}{(n)_{k - 1}}  \sum_{i_1,
    \ldots, i_{k - 1}} \varphi_{k - 1} (x_{i_1}, \ldots, x_{i_{k - 1}}) 
    \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{i = 1}^n f_k (x_i)\\
    & = & \frac{1}{(n)_{k - 1} n}  \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_{k - 1}} \sum_{i =
    1}^n \varphi_k (x_{i_1}, \ldots, x_{i_{k - 1}}, x_i)\\
    & = & \frac{1}{(n)_{k - 1} n}  \left( S_k + \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_{k - 1}}
    \sum_{i \in \{ i_1, \ldots, i_{k - 1} \}} \varphi_k (x_{i_1}, \ldots,
    x_{i_{k - 1}}, x_i) \right) .
  \end{eqnarray*}
Hence $\|A_n (\varphi_{k - 1}) A_n (f_k) - \frac{1}{(n)_{k - 1} n}S_k\|_{\infty}$ is able to be estimated now. And the difference $\|\frac{1}{(n)_k}S_k - \frac{1}{(n)_{k - 1} n}S_k\|_{\infty}$ is also readily estimated. Adding the two estimates should give you something like what Klenke wrote.

Comment: Sorry but what does the notation $(n)_k$ mean?

Comment: @varpi It's $(n)_k = n(n - 1) \dots (n - (k - 1))$.